# Normal ring which is not integrally closed integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Here, normal ring is a integral domain $A$ whose localization at every prime ideal is integrally closed integral domain.

Then, it is known that integrally closed integral domain is normal ring.
But I heard the converse does not hold in general.

Could you give me an example of the titled ring?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In some of the literature a normal ring is not required to be an integral domain. Perhaps what you've heard is related to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, a *normal ring* means a ring whose localizations at prime ideals are domains which are integrally closed in their field of fractions.

$\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ is such a ring, since its localizations are fields.

Comment: Here's [the DaRT query](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=118&L=127) for a normal ring that isn't a normal domain.  Also, this is at least the third time I've answered one of your questions and included a simple query like this. Perhaps you should try it out!  It's not hard...